# HTML select dropdown list

Tags: html

I want to have a drop down list using the select, option tag... but when it first appear I want it to have an information, such as "Please select a name" then the user clicks on the drop down list and selects from the available option... I tried to made the "Please select a name" as an option, but then the user will be able to select this... which is not what I want. Do I need to use javascript to have this feature or what do I need to do?

If there'a jquery way to do this, this would be much helpful

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have `<option value="">- Please select a name -</option>` as the first option and use JavaScript (and backend validation) to ensure the user has selected something other than an empty value.

Comment: but then as I said, it'll show up "Please select a name" in the list of options that can be chosen

Comment: I understand that. So what would you like instead?  A button that when clicked, is replaced with the dropdown?  (Not being sarcastic.. that would be an option, but needs to be degradable for accessability.)  If you want to stick with a dropdown only, I don't think there is any other way than what I mentioned.

Answer (score 109):

Try this:

```html
<select>
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select a name</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

When the page loads, this option will be selected by default. However, as soon as the drop-down is clicked, the user won't be able to re-select this option.

Comment: @smci At the time I posted this, I tested it in FF and it worked exactly as described. Not sure what version I was using back then though, but I just tested it in FF 8.0 and it still works.

Comment: Uhuh. At least it doesn't work with Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu canonical 1.0

Comment: This answer is perfect if combined with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14406006/1257652)

Comment: This option doesn't work. Use Musa's option and put validation on values selected.

Comment: @BBi7: Just tested the solution again in FF 43, Chrome 47 and IE11 on both Win 8.1 and Win 10, as well as Edge on Win 10. It still works exactly as described. Mentioning the browser and OS on which the solution doesn't work for you would help other people in deciding whether to use it or not.

Answer (score 43):

```html
<select>
    <option value="" style="display:none">Choose one provider</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

This way the user cannot see this option, but it shows in the select box.

Comment: On Mac 10.8.5, this works for me in Firefox 24.0 and Opera 18.0 but not in Chrome 29.0 or Safari 6.1.1.

Comment: Wow, this is amazingly brilliant and simple. It works in Chrome on Windows. Thank you.

Comment: The problem with this, is that it puts a big space on the bottom of the option-list. It does work though, as long as you're not too picky on that sort of thing. +1

Answer (score 10):

This is an old post, but this worked for me

```html
<select>
  <option value="" disabled selected>Please select a name...</option> 
  <option>this</option>
  <option>that</option>
</select>
```

Comment: IMO this is the most correct way to do it, and probably should be the accepted answer. Javascript solutions are unnecessary.

Answer (score 6):

```html
  <select name="test">
      <option hidden="true">Please select a name</option>
      <option value="Cash">Cash</option>
      <option value="Draft">Demand Draft No.</option>
      <option value="Cheque">Cheque No.</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this can help you resolve without JavaScript 
http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/forms/option.html

See DISABLE option

Comment: This is more proper than some javascript hack. I believe you'll have to make it selected AND disabled though. Also, you can use javascript to add the disabled attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Simple, I suppose. The onclick attribute works nicely...

```html
<select onchange="if(this.value == '') this.selectedIndex = 1; ">
  <option value="">Select an Option</option>
  <option value="one">Option 1</option>
  <option value="two">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

After a different option is selected, if the first option is selected, Option 1 will be selected. If you want an explanation on the javascript, just ask.

Comment: You don't really need JS for this, just basic HTML :)

Comment: He said a jQuery was ok, so why not go with client side validation. Unless it is sensitive information, no need to go with server side validation.

Edit: Saw your post. You were correct. Forgot that you could disable specific options.

Answer (score 2):

```
<select>
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select name</option>
  <option value="Tom">Tom</option>
  <option value="Marry">Marry</option>
  <option value="Jane">Jane</option>
  <option value="Harry">Harry</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to achieve the same for the jquery-ui selectmenu control then you have to set 'display: none' in the open event handler and add '-menu' to the id string.

```
<select id="myid">
<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select     name</option>
 <option value="Tom">Tom</option>
 <option value="Marry">Mary</option>
 <option value="Jane">Jane</option>
 <option value="Harry">Harry</option>
 </select>

$('select#listsTypeSelect').selectmenu({
  change: function( event, data ) {
    alert($(this).val());
},
open: function( event, ui ) {
    $('ul#myid-menu li:first-child').css('display', 'none');
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to necro an old post - but I found a better way of doing this

What I believe this poster wanted was :

```
<label for="mydropdown" datalabel="mydropdown">Country:</label>    
<select name="mydropdown">
    <option value="United States">United States</option>
    <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
    <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
    <option value="Other">Not Listed</option>
</select>
```

I found this information in another post while searching for this same answer - Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<select>
  <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select an Option</option>
  <option value="one">Option 1</option>
  <option value="two">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a JavaScript control that before the submit cheek that the selected option is different to your first option

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do this with JQuery...

using the jquery-watermark plugin (http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/)

```
$('#inputId').watermark('Please select a name');
```

works like a charm!!

There is some good documentation at that google code site.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is only compatible to HTML input and textarea elements!

Answer (score 0):

```
    <select>
         <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select a 
              developer position</option>
          <option value="1">Beginner</option>
          <option value="2">Expert</option>
     </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are looking for a placeholder for your select options, which has to be selected when no value is pre-selected, and cannot be selected by user, or seen.

```html
<select name="selectOne">
  <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Choose an option</option>
  <option value="this">This</option>
  <option value="that">That</option>
</select>
```