# Select menu "fake" option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I wonder, is it possible to show "Select one" by default as selected option but hide from options list when user clicks to open select menu? I mean, something like `placeholder`for text input field. Is there anyway to do it with js or something else? Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

Lets say we have select menu

```
<select>
<option value"">Select one...</option>
<option value"1">Option 1 </option>
...
</select>
```

What i'm gonna do is, remove `<option value"">Select one...</option>` from options list when user opens menu, and return back to default state when user closes menu.

Comment: can you provide a better example -- your question is not getting good answers *because it is not sufficiently clear*

Comment: I mean, remove this option when user clicks to open select menu and return back to default state when user closes menu. is it clear?

Comment: no it is not clear, you should click "edit" to improve and clarify your question with an example.

Comment: updated question. Please take a look

Comment: Similar question to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350937/html-select-dropdown-list), except that question did not want to make the unselectable caption disappear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
<SELECT NAME="browser" VALUE="" 
  onchange="var opt=this.options[0];if(opt.getAttribute('role')==='placeholder'&&!opt.selected)opt.parentNode.removeChild(opt);">
    <option role="placeholder" value="">Which Web browser do you use most often?</option>
    <OPTGROUP LABEL="Firefox">
      <OPTION LABEL="2.0 or higher">
        Firefox 2.0 or higher
      </OPTION>
      <OPTION LABEL="1.5.x">Firefox 1.5.x</OPTION>
      <OPTION LABEL="1.0.x">Firefox 1.0.x</OPTION>
    </OPTGROUP>
    <OPTGROUP LABEL="Microsoft Internet Explorer">
      <OPTION LABEL="7.0 or higher">
        Microsoft Internet Explorer 7.0 or higher
      </OPTION>
      <OPTION LABEL="6.x">Microsoft Internet Explorer 6.x</OPTION>
      <OPTION LABEL="5.x">Microsoft Internet Explorer 5.x</OPTION>
      <OPTION LABEL="4.x">Microsoft Internet Explorer 4.x</OPTION>
    </OPTGROUP>
    <OPTGROUP LABEL="Opera">
      <OPTION LABEL="9.0 or higher">Opera 9.0 or higher</OPTION>
      <OPTION LABEL="8.x">Opera 8.x</OPTION>
      <OPTION LABEL="7.x">Opera 7.x</OPTION>
    </OPTGROUP>
    <OPTION>Safari</OPTION>
    <OPTION>Other</OPTION>
  </SELECT>
```

`OPTION` with custom tag `role="placeholder"` must placed first inside `SELECT` to work properly.

Comment: yepp. something like that. But can we get this option back on close, and how to return menu to default state after page refresh?

Comment: can we do it with `.append()`, `.remove()`?

Comment: Set id to your select object, then `theSelect = document.getElementById('selectId');
theSelect.insertBefore(newElement, theSelect.firstChild)`. See
[insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.insertBefore). To get it executed on page refresh, try adding code to <body onload="...">

Comment: @Tural Teyyuboglu: I dontn known about event like `ondropdown` for `SELECT`.  And what if user changes value with keyboard: tab, left|right|top|bottom arrows? Potentialy You can use `onfocus` | `onblur` events or `onclick`. But this is more complex. In above solution when SELECT is closed and no other (valid) option is selected _placeholder_ is not removed and stay displayed. When valid option selected, why you need to revert back? http://jsfiddle.net/T4ty3/

Comment: @Tural Teyyuboglu: What is not clear? What is not works? See example link on my previous comment. I tested with FF7. What browser you uses?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```html
<form>
<select onchange="document.getElementById('placeholder').disabled=true">
   <option selected="selected" id="placeholder">please select something</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
</form>
```

In this example, the option remains visible to the user, but is not clickable.

Comment: no. remove this option when user clicks to open select menu and return back to default state when user closes menu. is it clear?

Comment: Maybe `onfocus` / `onblur` then? onfocus remove the node, onblur bind it back again. However, after you remove the "fake" option when user clicks the menu, he is unable to select that "fake" option ever again (because any time he clicks it again, the option is removed), so why would you like to do that?

Comment: `disabled` property of OPTION have boolean value in javascript. More valid is to set it to `true`|`false`: `document.getElementById('placeholder').disabled=true;` MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLOptionElement

Comment: @qbk You code is correct, because in javascript: `"disabled"` works as `true` and `""` works as `false`. But more proper to use `true` and `false` for `disabled`.